# How to make a new column in a data frame based on results of two columns in separate data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df1:

```
   ZIP Weekend Sales
1 60657       1    2
2 60657       1    1
3 60657       1    1
4 60641       0    2
5 60641       0    NA
6 60607       0    0
7 60607       0    1
8 60628       0    1
```

And a separate df2:

```
    ZCTA   ZIP Population
6  60657 60657      82739
7  60609 60609      64906
10 60612 60612      33472
13 60641 60641     40603
14 60616 60616      48433
15 60607 60607      84155
16 60628 60628      92084
17 60619 60619      63825
```

I would like to make two additional columns to df2. One column will be SalesSum. I would like to sum the total sales score for each zip code like so:

output:

```
    ZCTA   ZIP Population   Sales
6  60657 60657      82739    4
7  60609 60609      64906    0
10 60612 60612      33472    0 
13 60641 60641      40603    2
14 60616 60616      48433    0
15 60607 60607      84155    1
16 60628 60628      92084    1
17 60619 60619      63825    0
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Base-R

```
SalesByZip <- sapply(split(df1$Sales,df1$ZIP), sum)
df2$Sales <- lapply(df2$ZIP, function(x) SalesByZip[grepl(x, names(SalesByZip))] )


> df2
    ZCTA   ZIP Population Sales
6  60657 60657      82739     4
7  60609 60609      64906      
10 60612 60612      33472      
13 60641 60641      40603     2
14 60616 60616      48433      
15 60607 60607      84155     1
16 60628 60628      92084     1
17 60619 60619      63825
```

Edit:

If you'd like the zeroes to actually be in the list just add

```
df2$Sales[sapply(df2$Sales,length)==0] <- 0


> df2
    ZCTA   ZIP Population Sales
6  60657 60657      82739     4
7  60609 60609      64906     0
10 60612 60612      33472     0
13 60641 60641      40603     2
14 60616 60616      48433     0
15 60607 60607      84155     1
16 60628 60628      92084     1
17 60619 60619      63825     0
```

**Explanation:**

`SalesByZip <- sapply(split(df1$Sales,df1$ZIP), sum)` Here, we split the data from df1 with `split(df1$Sales,df1$ZIP)` This returns only the sales seperated by the ZIP codes. then we wrap that in `sapply(..., sum)` which will sum each split.

Now `lapply(df2$ZIP, ... )` This will pass the lines from `df2$ZIP` one at a time into our function `function(x) SalesByZip[grepl(x, names(SalesByZip))]` This function is accessing the corresponding value of `SalesByZip` that matches the ZIP we passed into the function.

**Addressing comment:**

The following solution adds in the zereos without the added line above and ensures `class(df2$Sales)` = `"numeric"`

```
SalesByZip <- sapply(split(df1$Sales,df1$ZIP), sum)
df2$Sales <- sapply(df2$ZIP, function(x){x<-SalesByZip[grepl(x, names(SalesByZip))];ifelse(length(x)==0,0,x)} )
```

Comment: This is good, can you explain what the steps are and if I wanted to do a different column than sales how I would modify? Also, added an NA I found in my data, make a difference?

Comment: @Evan I've added an explanation to the code above. If you want to change what is calculated from where, you should only need to change the `SalesByZip` line.Please consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Comment: I will accept the answer soon. I am trying to plot the data with a hist(df2$Sales) and it tells me that it needs to be numeric. When I check class(df2$Sales) it is a list. I tried to as.numeric(as.character(df2$Sales)) but it forced NAs by coercion. Help?

Comment: @Evan, `df2$Sales <- unlist(df2$Sales)`

Comment: @Even, I've edited the answer to add the "Addressing comment" section. This new code will do everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this answer with a bit of `tidyverse` :

```
df <- read.table("df1.txt")
df2 <- read.table("df2.txt")

library(tidyverse)

#aggregate by ZIP
tt <- df %>% group_by(ZIP) %>% summarise(Sales = sum(Sales))
tt

# create the new column
df2$Sales <- 0

# add values at the right place
df2[match(tt$ZIP, df2$ZIP), ]$Sales <- tt$Sales

###### a more tidyverse version (Mike idea) #####
df2 <- left_join(df2, tt, by = "ZIP")

# to supress NA without tidy
df2$Sales[is.na(df2$Sales)] = 0
```

df2 :

```
   ZCTA   ZIP Population Sales
6  60657 60657      82739     4
7  60609 60609      64906     0
10 60612 60612      33472     0
13 60641 60641      40603     2
14 60616 60616      48433     0
15 60607 60607      84155     1
16 60628 60628      92084     1
17 60619 60619      63825     0
```

Comment: I believe that this would only work if all the ZIP's in df2 are unique due to the `match` call.

Comment: I'm getting an error here

Comment: if you are using tidyverse your last step might be a bit better if you used `left_join` or `inner_join` depending on if you need to keep everything in the left hand side or zips that are in both dfs

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(ZIP) %>%
  summarise(Sales = sum(Sales, na.rm = T)) %>%
  right_join(df2) %>%
  mutate(Sales = coalesce(Sales, 0L))

# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#     ZIP Sales  ZCTA Population
#   <int> <int> <int>      <int>
# 1 60657     4 60657      82739
# 2 60609     0 60609      64906
# 3 60612     0 60612      33472
# 4 60641     2 60641      40603
# 5 60616     0 60616      48433
# 6 60607     1 60607      84155
# 7 60628     1 60628      92084
# 8 60619     0 60619      63825
```

---

Or replace `summarise` with `tally`. It can remove missing values when summing. It's equivalent to set `na.rm = T` in `sum`.

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(ZIP) %>%
  tally(Sales, name = "Sales") %>% 
  right_join(df2) %>% 
  mutate(Sales = coalesce(Sales, 0L))
```